# Python displaying to user Tkinter Application Status

Tags: python, tkinter, busyindicator

I have Python/Tkinter Application that, at 2-3 points of time, locks the main screen for 30 seconds to several minutes, as it has a lot of stuff it needs to do.

I have it in my mind that during those points in time, it would be a more polished application if instead of locking the main screen for the duration of the task, I could separate the computationally intensive part of the application from the main thread, and display some sort feedback to the user as to what is happening...whether that is a modal status window, or a spinning cat animation.

I am unfortunately a little lost as to what's a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could look up `concurrent.futures`, `multiprocessing`, `threading` and using tkinter `.after()` method. I recently posted my question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42221437/5722359) on using `concurrent.futures`. I have successfully implemented the model described in Mark Summerfield's book and I recommend you give `concurrent.futures` a try. You still need 1 or 2 commands from `threading` and `multiprocessing`. My code worked well and there is no latency issue with tkinter. Note: This working code is more detailed than the [example code in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42221437/5722359), which I used to show that a python class could be used to host the concurrent.future codes instead of a separate python file. Hope you find something suitable for your coding needs.

Happen to see a recent answer that relates to answering your question.
`.after()` with `threading` [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42424229/5722359). It has other links.