# TKINTER window gets freezes when after command is called

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a small tkinter program that allows user to enter **name** and **date** from the user and store it to a text file.

Everything works fine. But when **after** command gets executed then everything gets freezes for 2000 milli-seconds as I have mention in the code below. I am not able to click at any widget when **after** command is executing.

I have read solution of same problem but didn't solve by any of them.

**How can I run my script smoothly even after "after" command is called?**

**CODE**

```
from Tkinter import *


def submit():
    # Gets executed when submit button is clicked

    label = Label(label_frame, text='SUBMITTED')
    label.grid(row=3, column=0)

    with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
        get_name = name_entry.get()
        get_date = date_entry.get()

        f.write('{} {}'.format(get_name, get_date))

    root.update()
    root.after(2000, label.grid_forget())

    # Everything gets paused / freezed when it executes after command

root = Tk()
root.geometry('350x200')

frame = Frame()
label_frame = Frame()

# Setting name label and its entry
name_label = Label(frame, text='NAME')
name_entry = Entry(frame, width=30)
name_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Setting date label and its entry
date_label = Label(frame, text='DATE')
date_entry = Entry(frame, width=30)
date_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
date_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

# Setting submit button
submit_button = Button(frame, text='ADD', width=15, command=submit)
submit_button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=5)

# Placing frames to window
frame.place(x=50, y=20)
label_frame.place(x=130, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why you think you need the after method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to easily avoid Tkinter freezing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422139/how-to-easily-avoid-tkinter-freezing)

Comment: Multitasking is your solution, so you won't put your GUI to sleep. Internet is full of tutorials and examples of `threading` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following excerpt from the [effbot](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112030233/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) documentation on `after`:

> **`after(delay_ms, callback=None, *args)`**
>
> Registers an alarm callback that is called after a given time.
>
> This method registers a callback function that will be called after a given number of milliseconds. Tkinter only guarantees that the callback will not be called earlier than that; if the system is busy, the actual delay may be much longer.
>
> You can also omit the callback. If you do, this method simply waits for the given number of milliseconds, without serving any events (same as `time.sleep(delay_ms*0.001)`).
>
> *delay_ms*
> Delay, in milliseconds.
>
> *callback*
> The callback. This can be any callable object.

When you call

```
root.after(2000, label.grid_forget())
```

you pass `2000` as the delay in milliseconds, which is good. You also pass `label.grid_forget()` as the callback. However, `label.grid_forget()` is not a callable object as it should be, it's a function call. Therefore, it will be executed, and its return value will be passed as the callback. Because the return value of `.grid_forget()` is `None`, you're actually calling

```
root.after(2000, None)
```

In the information above, you can see that `None` is the default value for the callback, and that when you omit the callback it simply waits for the given number of milliseconds, without serving any events. Since you're passing `None` as the callback, you're basically omitting the callback, so tkinter freezes.

You can fix this by passing the function object (which is callable) as the callback, instead of calling the function:

```
root.after(2000, label.grid_forget)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation is crystal clear.