# How to quit tkinter window with schedule running?

Tags: python

I am creating a scheduler for a few different python scripts and I am using a tkinter window to take in the usernames and passwords for the servers I am accessing.

I seem to be able to get the scheduler to work, but when it does, it now breaks the mainloop so the window no longer responds.

I have tried putting the mainloop inside the loop that keeps the schedule running, but that causes the scheduler to stop functioning.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess
import schedule
import time

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.e_user_label = tk.Label(self, text="Email Username")
        self.e_pw_label = tk.Label(self, text="Email Password")
        self.e_account_label = tk.Label(self, text="Email Account")
        self.email_user = tk.Entry(self, width=30)
        self.email_pw = tk.Entry(self, show="*", width=30)
        self.email_account = tk.Entry(self, width=30)
        self.start_scheduler = tk.Button(self, text="Start Scheduler", 
            command=self.check_email_request)
        self.e_user_label.pack()
        self.email_user.pack()
        self.e_pw_label.pack()
        self.email_pw.pack()
        self.e_account_label.pack()
        self.email_account.pack()
        self.start_scheduler.pack()

    def check_email_request(self):
        call_email_script = 'call python email_monitor.py {} {} {}'.format(self.email_user.get(), 
            self.email_pw.get(), self.email_account.get())
        completed = subprocess.run(call_email_script, shell=True)
        print('returncode:', completed.returncode)

    def print_stuff(self):
        schedule.every(1).minutes.do(self.check_email_request)
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
            w.mainloop() #my failed attempt to solve this problem

w = MainWindow()
w.mainloop()
```

Expected the scheduler to keep calling my check_email_request function every 1 minute. If I don't include the main loop in schedule loop, the window no longer functions. When I include the mainloop, the scheduler no longer functions.

Comment: You don't need the `schedule` module at all; Tkinter's `.after()` method can delay the function call by a minute, without blocking anything (and then the function will use `.after()` again to call itself the next minute).

Comment: Is your mainloop not being interrupted by your function? [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422139/how-to-easily-avoid-tkinter-freezing) about threading and tkinter

Comment: @jasonharper I think  ```.after()``` would work for this one that is running on a regular interval. I was planning on adding another schedule that would run every Sunday at a designated time. I should have included an example. I think ```.after()``` will be good to use if I don't use a specified day, though. Thanks!

@MattM I'll try that method. That sounds like a good way to make it flexible.

Comment: Creating a thread solved the problem. I changed 
```command=self.check_email_request``` in the for the button action to 
```command=threading.Thread(group=None, target=self.check_email_request).start```. The main window stays active and the schedule runs. I get an exception when I close the window, but this is a smaller problem to solve.

Comment: Great. You're going to always want any functions to be in a thread that is different from tkinter's, else it will freeze up during execution. Feel free to post that exception if you dont figure it out

Comment: @Profcrab *"I get an exception when I close the window"*: You have to stop your `Thread` before `.destroy()` the `.mainloop()`.