# Can't figure out how to correctly apply threading to stop tkinter from freezing

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have a Tkinter GUI that is running a pretty lengthy calculations on the background. I want to keep the window responsive while this is happening and also for the user to see the progress bars of various actions (right now it freezes after a few seconds).

Here's the rough structure of my code (only the relevant bits):

```
class ImputerGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self._create_interface()
        self.root.mainloop()


    def _create_interface(self):
        self.root.geometry("770x790")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.root.winfo_toplevel().title("Model encoder")

        self._create_frames()
        self._create_buttons()
        # Other stuff

    def _create_buttons(self):
        process_data = tk.Button(self.lower, text='Process data',
                                 width=30, bg='#f2fafc',
                                 font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'),
                                 justify=tk.CENTER,
                                 command=self._process_data)
        process_data.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10, padx=30, rowspan=2, sticky=tk.N + tk.S)

    def _process_data(self):
        if self.bmf_filename:
            threading.Thread(target=self._convert_bmf_file()).start()
        else:
            threading.Thread(target=self._load_csv_file()).start()
        
        # Bunch of other calculations
        self._save_output()
```

I had a look at [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422139/how-to-easily-avoid-tkinter-freezing) and tried to use `threading` module to spawn calculation tasks in their separate threads so that `mainloop()` can continue running. But for some reason this doesn't seem to have any effect on the behaviour.

I've also seen [answers to the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop/) that I can possibly achieve the desired result using `after()` but not sure how to apply it to my code.

Comment: Change `target=self._convert_bmf_file()` to `target=self._convert_bmf_file` and `target=self._load_csv_file()` to `target=self._load_csv_file`.  You should pass the name of the function without (), otherwise the function will be executed immediately.

Comment: Yeah, that did it. Thanks a lot for the help!