# Embedding Lightkurve graphs into Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been succesfully creating graphs with the lightkurve library from data retrieved from MAST and it all seems to work fine, however, when trying to implement this into Tkinter the program gets stuck and does nothing, is there something wrong in my implementation?

```
import tkinter as tk
import lightkurve as lk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg # enables to embed matplotlib graphs into tkinter modules

# create window
window = tk.Tk()

# edit window
window.title("Graph")
window.geometry("500x500")

# download data
flux_graph = lk.search_targetpixelfile("KIC 7461601", author="Kepler", cadence='long', quarter=10).download()

# create graph
fig = Figure(figsize=(5,5))
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(flux_graph)

# load graph into tkinter
graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,window) # function that loads figure into window
graph.get_tk_widget().pack() # get the tkinter widget and pack it into the window

# activate
tk.mainloop()
```

I've tried plotting the graphs with mathplotlib separately and they work fine, i don't know what's wrong when embedding them into tkinter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422139/how-to-easily-avoid-tkinter-freezing